# How to compare all column records between two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare two table records. and find which one is not matching. I am not looking for which record is not found in one table

Example: I have 2 databases called `DBLive` and `DBLiveBackup`, both with the same tables. One of the table is `ProductDetails`.

It has 15 columns; I want to compare the `DBLive` with `DBLiveBackup` database where records are not matching.

**Update**

[I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39353650/7734785). I almost looking for the same. But I cannot compare it one by one column like below code. because I have to compare whole database.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.MSISDN = B.MSIDN
WHERE A.firstname != B.firstname 
   OR A.lastname != B.Lastname
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: This has been answered lots of times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dfundako If you gave a link to a duplicate, we could vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @dfundako can you give where is the link. because i found only where is not exists in another table. But i am not looking for where records are not exists. I am looking for comparison of all fiels is not matching with one another

Comment: @andrewMortan i agree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare data between two table in different databases using Sql Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606175/how-to-compare-data-between-two-table-in-different-databases-using-sql-server-20)

Comment: Try using `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT`, e.g. `SELECT * FROM [DatabaseA].[Schema].[Table] EXCEPT SELECT * FROM [DatabaseB].[Schema].[Table];`

Comment: @RichardHansell that would make a fine answer